# Show MODAL in onsen ui while data is fetching in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

I am trying to fetch data from server. Since its fetching i want to show a modal till its not loaded completely.

Here is what i am using.

```
<ons-page ng-controller="directoryControl">

      <ons-modal var="modal">
        <ons-icon icon="ion-load-c" spin="true"></ons-icon>
        <br><br>
        Please wait.<br>Closing in 2 seconds.
      </ons-modal>

      <ons-list>

        <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="list-item-container" ng-repeat="PostCategory in PostCategories">
          <ons-row>
            <ons-col>
              <div class="name">
                {{PostCategory.title}}
              </div>
            </ons-col>
          </ons-row>
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
    </ons-page>
```

There is how my modal looks like in angularjs.

```
var module = angular.module('app', ['onsen']);
    module.controller('directoryControl', function($scope, $http) {
    ons.ready(function() {

                    //console.log($scope.username + ", " + $scope.password);
                    modal.show();

                    var responsePromise = $http.get("http://www.mywebsitepadth.com/api/get_category_index/");
                    responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        modal.hide();
                    });
                    responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        alert("ajax didnt work");
                    });
        });
    });
```

May i know why this is not displaying the modal when i am doing it `modal.show();`?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, unless `ons` is a global variable, it doesn't exist in your controller code, so `ons.ready()` will never fire.

Comment: Yes its showing error in  modal.show(); this line. When i am checking through google chrome console. Says SHOW is not a defined property.

Comment: Is `modal` also a global variable? If not, `modal.show()` won't exist.

Comment: No i dont think so. How can i define that?

Comment: I use this as a reference http://codepen.io/onsen/pen/devIg/

Comment: Have you used `ons.bootstrap()` anywhere in your code? It looks like that's where the `modal` variable gets initiated.

Comment: `ons` is global and `modal` is created in the directive when you use `var="modal"`, so that's not the problem. This is a Codepen example with modal in AngularJS: http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/qdBPKP

Comment: Thank Fran for the interest. The example you gave was really helpful..but i have to call my var module = angular.module('app', ['onsen']); "module" also. As without this my app wont load. So can you please recommend something?

Comment: Should be the same since `ons.bootstrap` also returns an Angular module object. Just remember to add `ng-app="app"` in your code. http://onsen.io/reference/ons.html#method-bootstrap

Comment: Hello, Please check http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGxyzd while you load "directory" page it takes spin, instead of that i want to load the modal. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is, just call `modal.show()` in directory.html's controller and `modal.hide()` when you know that "directory" is loaded. If directory is loaded with an HTTP request, call `modal.hide()` on $http...success();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your model direct child of body like this.

```
<body>
   <ons-modal var="modal">
        <ons-icon icon="ion-load-c" spin="true"></ons-icon>
        <br><br>
        Please wait.<br>Closing in 2 seconds.
      </ons-modal>
```

---

This way you'll be able to access modal anywhere in your any controller.
Now your controller should be like this.

```
module.controller('directoryControl', function($scope, $http) {

                    //console.log($scope.username + ", " + $scope.password);
                    modal.show();

                    var responsePromise = $http.get("http://www.mywebsitepadth.com/api/get_category_index/");
                    responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        modal.hide();
                    });
                    responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        alert("ajax didnt work");
                    });
    });
```

Comment: Its never too late! Thank you for looking into the issue...

My problem was solved a long back. But i hope this will resolved someones else issue.